# Python Notebook Invoke Endpoint Sagemaker from Local

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to invoke an Amazon Sagemaker Endpoint from a local python notebook. This is the code I am using.

```
import boto3

aws_access_key_id = '...............'
aws_secret_access_key = '................'
tkn = '..........'
region_name = '............'

amz = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime',
                   aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                   aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
                   aws_session_token=tkn,
                   region_name=region_name)


response = amz.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName='mymodel',
    Body=b'bytes'
)
```

However, this doesn't work. Do I have to specify something else in *Body* ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use boto3 session . I assume you already prepared jsons and your aws credentials are already on ~/.aws/credentials.

```
import boto3, json, sagemaker

sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
role              = "YOUR-SAGEMAKER-EXECUTION-ROLE"
region            = boto3.Session().region_name
endpointName=     'YOUR ENDPOINT NAME'
predictor = sagemaker.predictor.RealTimePredictor(
               endpointName, 
               sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session, 
               content_type="application/json")
d='YOUR JSON LINES- YOU CAN OPEN WITH PYTHON BUILT IN FUNCTIONS'
response=predictor.predict(json.dumps(d))
```

response has the answer body which formatted in json. You can parse it and use your results.

Answer (score 0):

Each endpoint expects different binary data. By specifying `Body=b'bytes'` you're passing the bytes of the string literal *bytes*, while you should be passing some actual input data to infer off.

According to the [doc](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-runtime.html#SageMakerRuntime.Client.invoke_endpoint), I recommended to include the relevant ContentType, of the input data you're sending.

You said:

> However, this doesn't work.

What is the error you're getting back?